# How to fix the issue 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'?

Tags: android, arrays, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

This is the error occurs in logcat,can anyone tell what's the meaning?

```
private int getDayIdxInTrip(int position) {
DayTagItem item = null;
    Integer dayIdx = -1;
    try {
        if (mTripItems.get(position).mViewType == TripDetailAdapter.DAYTAG_TYPE) {
            item = (DayTagItem) mTripItems.get(position);
        } else {
            Logger.e(TAG, "Wrong view type found on position == "
                    + position);
            position--;
            return getDayIdxInTrip(position);
        }
        dayIdx = Integer
                .parseInt(item.mDayIdx != null
                        && !item.mDayIdx.trim().equals("")
                        && !item.mDayIdx.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null") ? item.mDayIdx
                        : "0");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "getDayIdxInTrip() error!"+e.getMessage());
    }
    Logger.i(TAG,"returned"+dayIdx);
    return dayIdx;
}
```

> 03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>      03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):     at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:4180)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:3017)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2117)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3377)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1746)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1117)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2092)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1730)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1794)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>   03-05 16:19:10.092: E/AndroidRuntime(29009):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Can you post the code for where the app crash?

Comment: This is not helping, unless the Java code is seen

Comment: Seems like he's using listeners in a ListView and messed up the indexes. Do you use header or bottom views?

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (usually) means that you are accessing an array or a list with an index that is either smaller than 0 or larger than or equal to the size of the array/list. In this case it seems to happen when you are scrolling an AbsListView, so most likely you are changing the underlying array without notifying the list of this, causing it to believe it has more elements than it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation:

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
>   index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
>   size of the array.

Example:

```
int myArray = new int[10];
myArray[11] = 123;
```

Without the code we cannot help much.

Comment: i guess it comes from the `position--; return getDayIdxInTrip(position);`